# Правило йотированного и

Tags: фонетика

Недавно делали фонетический разбор слова "соловьи". По правилу "и" после мягкого знака обозначает два звука "й" и "и". В одной статье было написано, что есть еще одна позиция, когда и обозначает два звука, как в слове соловьи. Но эта позиция не изучается в школе. Нигде не смогла найти информацию об этом. Может быть кто-то знает вторую позицию йотированного и?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Такое может быть после другого и. Например, в косвенных падежах существительных на -ий, -ия, -ие: *о Васил**ии**, о Мар**ии**, о сочинен**ии***. Читается как [ийи].

Но это не общепринятая трактовка, не все авторы видят там именно [йи], да и не все так произносят. Можно передавать и как [и:] и как [и'и] (прерывистое и).

Зато другие полагают, что призвук лидирующего йота у [и] (особенно ударного) есть в любой позиции поле гласного, например в имени Луи. Но все это очень спорно, поэтому в школе и не изучают.